# Fully expanding header macros to get their numeric values for external use

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I have a complicated header file with lots of dependencies on other earlier-defined macros that layout the memory map of an embedded system. For example:

```
#define RAM_BASE           (0x40000000)
#define RAM_SIZE           (0x10000000) 
#define SECURE_RAM_SIZE    (0x00200000)
#define SECURE_RAM_BASE    (RAM_BASE + RAM_SIZE - SECURE_RAM_SIZE)
```

For many reasons I need the result of `SECURE_RAM_BASE` outside of the compiled program. So, my thought was to use the C preprocessor to expand these macros and `awk` the result as needed. However, the macro expansion with `cpp -dD <file>` was exactly as shown above (less extra white space).

I was expecting something like this:

```
RAM_BASE           0x40000000
RAM_SIZE           0x10000000
SECURE_RAM_SIZE    0x00200000
SECURE_RAM_BASE    0x4fe00000
```

But it seems (at least as far as I interpret the man page) that such expansion may only be accessible when the macros are actually used *in code*. Even still, the following code-use:

```
printf("Base: 0x%x\n", SECURE_RAM_BASE);
```

Expands to:

```
printf("Base: 0x%x\n", ((0x40000000) + (0x10000000) - (0x00200000)));
```

Is there a way to produce a 'fully-computed' expansion result using the C preprocessor?

Comment: The preprocessor does not calculate. What you observed is the normal behaviour.

Comment: @Yunnosch I was unaware. I assumed it followed the calculations through to the final result. Otherwise the compiler has to come back later and do it anyway.

Comment: Actually, pre-processed output should not contain macro definitions at all. It should only contain their substitutions. I'd say, for your purposes, the best you can do is to define variables with values equal to those macros, and than grep for those variables.

Comment: I am trying to find out the meaning of you `-dD`, because actually I'd use `-E`. That won't help either however, because my first comment stands.

Comment: @Yunnosch From the cpp manual: `-dD Like -dM except in two respects: it does not include the predefined macros, and it outputs both the #define directives and the result of preprocessing`. With my assumption that cpp carried through the final calculations maintaining the `#define` portion of the macro definition seemed to be a way to get the expanded value. The `-E` option is not defined in the manual but it is mentioned. I saw others using `-E` for this purpose.

Comment: @Yunnosch: The preprocessor doesn't calculate unless it needs to do so.  `#if SECURE_RAM_BASE < RAM_BASE` requires a preprocessor calculation.  But when expanding a macro, the preprocessor doesn't calculate — primarily because it doesn't have the entire context of the expression to guide it.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Good point. Thanks. So it should have been "The preprocessor does not calculate **for expanding macros**."

Comment: @Yunnosch — 'for' or 'while' expanding macros — yes.

Comment: Can you tell us about "outside of the compiled program" please? Perhaps this is another case of the X-Y-problem.

Comment: @thebusybee I do not know what you mean. But I am compiling a multi-stage firmware that is has three binaries all linked at three addresses. I partitioned the available RAM into three regions. At link-time I want to be able to compute the final addresses and pass them to the linker as necessary. In order to get these addresses I need the expansions of the header file that lays out the partitioning scheme. The addresses are also used "_inside_" the compiled program, but I also need them "_outside_" for this purpose.

Comment: If you intend to process output using `awk`anyway, why don't you use it to compute the arithmetic operations as well?

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a way to produce a 'fully-computed' expansion result using the C preprocessor?

Why, yes, there is.  (Incidentally, boost preprocessor solves a similar problem using its concept of [slots](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/ref/slot.html); but the solution here is more tailored to this use case and hex outputs).  Comments to your question already lay the ground rules... C preprocessor macro expansion cannot evaluate expressions.  But C preprocessor conditional directives can.  Conditional directives don't *reduce* expressions, but with a bit of work you can get the CPP to coax the results out.  Since your goal is to simply get results out, you're not actually limited by macro evaluation.

**High level approach**

Given those constraints, you want a file devoted to evaluating and printing an expression (let's say it's called `print_expression.h`).  The evaluation should be performed by an include directive; i.e., `#include "print_expression.h"`; this way, we can use the one CPP tool capable of evaluating expressions (viz, conditional directives) to do so.  We can simply have this file evaluate the expression `EXPRESSION`; you can `#define` this before the include.  Since you're going to reuse this for multiple macros that expand to expressions, we may want to preface the evaluation result with `EXPRESSION_LABEL`, which you can define as something.  Since this is a preprocessor program rather than a "normal" header, it can helpfully clean up after itself and skip inclusion guards so you can immediately reuse it.

**Driving the solution**

So for now ignore the details, and assume this just works... to generate something akin to the outputs you want on your sample header, you would include the header, and then need to pump this utility as follows:

```
#define EXPRESSION_LABEL 8RAM_BASE
#define EXPRESSION RAM_BASE
#include "print_expression.h"
#define EXPRESSION_LABEL 8RAM_SIZE
#define EXPRESSION RAM_SIZE
#include "print_expression.h"
```

...and so on.  But you don't need this file (assuming your cpp takes stdin); you mentioned awk, so assuming you also have sed and bash (and maybe a gnu like `-P` flag to your cpp to strip `#line` directives and clutter):

```
(echo '#include "complicated_header.h"' ;
 echo RAM_BASE,RAM_SIZE,SECURE_RAM_BASE,SECURE_RAM_SIZE | \
sed -e 's/,/\n/g' -e 's/.*/#define EXPRESSION_LABEL 8&\n#define EXPRESSION &\n#include "print_expression.h"/g' ) | cpp -E -P
```

Something like this is probably what you want to do, since from your question it sounds like you're going to do more processing on the outputs as well given specific extracted evaluated values.  Note that I'm prepending a `8` to the expression labels; this in CPP-ese makes it a "pp-number" that can't possibly evaluate... you can strip it out on the output (maybe with a `cut -c 2-`).

**The reusable calculator (by description)**

To make `print_expression.h` isn't too complicated, but it's going to be a big file, so I'll just outline the concept rather than inline it here (but see below).  I'll assume you want your output to be an 8 nibble hex number in hex format.  What you want to do then is to define a macro for each nibble in this hex number, to be pasted together when producing the output; the definition of each nibble macro will be given by evaluating a `#if/#elif/#else/#endif` chain that specifically checks the value for that nibble.  To make this a bit easier and repetitive (so you can copy/paste/replace it into being), you can have a helper macro evaluate `EXPRESSION` and shift the nibble in.  So to get you started, your file looks something like this:

```
#define RESULT_NIBBLE(NDX_) (((EXPRESSION)>>(NDX_*4))&0xF)
#if   RESULT_NIBBLE(7)==0xF
#define RESULT_NIBBLE_7 F
#elif RESULT_NIBBLE(7)==0xE
#define RESULT_NIBBLE_7 E
#elif RESULT_NIBBLE(7)==0xD
#define RESULT_NIBBLE_7 D
...
#elif RESULT_NIBBLE(7)==0x1)
#define RESULT_NIBBLE_7 1
#else
#define RESULT_NIBBLE_7 0
#endif
```

Following this, create a chain to define `RESULT_NIBBLE_6` down to `RESULT_NIBBLE_0`.  Once you finally get to the end, you just need to paste all of this onto `0x` with an indirect paste, dump the results by invoking the macros, then clean up to make yourself ready for the next usage:

```
#define HEXRESULT(A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H) HEXRESULTI(A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H)
#define HEXRESULTI(A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H) 0x ## A ## B ## C ## D ## E ## F ## G ## H

EXPRESSION_LABEL HEXRESULT(RESULT_NIBBLE_7,RESULT_NIBBLE_6,RESULT_NIBBLE_5,RESULT_NIBBLE_4,RESULT_NIBBLE_3,RESULT_NIBBLE_2,RESULT_NIBBLE_1,RESULT_NIBBLE_0)

#undef HEXRESULTI
#undef HEXRESULT
#undef RESULT_NIBBLE_7
#undef RESULT_NIBBLE_6
#undef RESULT_NIBBLE_5
#undef RESULT_NIBBLE_4
#undef RESULT_NIBBLE_3
#undef RESULT_NIBBLE_2
#undef RESULT_NIBBLE_1
#undef RESULT_NIBBLE_0
#undef EXPRESSION
#undef EXPRESSION_LABEL
```

**Brief demo**

[This demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9c71dda78f2c0760) emulates the solution good enough for single-file online demonstration.  Note that lines `27-317` effectively is a viable working `print_expression.h` in full.

Comment: Extending that to 64-bit integers doesn't bear thinking about (though it would be more tedious than difficult), but it works OK for 32-bit integers.  Ouch, though!

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to produce a 'fully-computed' expansion result using the C preprocessor?

No it is not possible. The C preprocessor only calculates anything in expressions after `#if` and `#elif`. In simple terms, the C preprocessor works in most cases as a string replacement. It sees `SECURE_RAM_BASE` it substitutes it for `(RAM_BASE + RAM_SIZE - SECURE_RAM_SIZE)` and the substitutes it for `((0x40000000) + (0x10000000) - (0x00200000))`. No calculation is done except in `#if` and `#endif`, only string substitution.

That said..., obviously you can:

```
#define RAM_BASE           (0x40000000)
#define RAM_SIZE           (0x10000000) 
#define SECURE_RAM_SIZE    (0x00200000)
#define SECURE_RAM_BASE_CALC    (RAM_BASE + RAM_SIZE - SECURE_RAM_SIZE)

#if SECURE_RAM_BASE_CALC == 1
#define SECURE_RAM_BASE 1
#elif SECURE_RAM_BASE_CALC == 2
#define SECURE_RAM_BASE 2
#elif SECURE_RAM_BASE_CALC == 3
#define SECURE_RAM_BASE 3
// ...
// ca. about 0x4fe00000 * 2 = 2680160256 =~ 2 bilion! more lines...
// ...
#elif SECURE_RAM_BASE_CALC == 0x4fe00000
#define SECURE_RAM_BASE 0x4fe00000
#endif
```

But this is way overkill.

Comment: Technically the preprocessor operates on a stream of tokens, not on a string.

Comment: "But this is way overkill" [...understatement of the day](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b717a0d94f65745a).

Answer (score 0):

1. You could write a simple C program that includes that header(s) and prints the result.
2. You could even let it print the linker command line(s).
3. Finally you could let this tiny program execute the command(s).

Now it's up to you with what stage you'll be most happy.

Comment: I've done 1 but it's certainly non-ideal. I was hoping for a nice cpp + grep/awk solution in the Makefile, but another step isn't terrible.

Comment: Well, as you seem to compile some C programs, one more will not hurt, for sure. ;-) And there will be no dependency on other tools like grep and (g)awk.

Comment: One problem with writing a program that includes the header and prints the results is that it often must be executed on a host/build platform rather than on the target platform. In that case, it is a different C implementation and may have different arithmetic due to different widths of integer types and other issues. One workaround to get the correct results is to use GCC’s `asm` extension to generate fake “assembly” code that includes the values as an immediate operand (`%i`, if I recall correctly), then compile with `-S` to generate assembly and extract the values from it.